# Permission denied (publickey) - bitnami at AWS (Wordpress site) - Connecting with PC

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, bitnami

I face following issues when trying to connect from my PS using either PowerShell or Cygwin to AWS on which my Wordpress site is hosted (Bitnami).

(I simply what to log in to the server either this way or using Putty as described here ([LINK][1] **Putty** is throwing an error "**using username bitnami. Server refused our key. No supported authentication methods available. server sent publickey**")

What I tried so far:
I execute either or both of the following commands...

```
chmod 600 <key-pair-from-aws>.pem
chmod 400 <key-pair-from-aws>.pem
```

*(When I logged in to ec2 instance, under Key Pairs section I saw an entry, but I could not download it. That's why I generated a new key pair and that is the file I am using in the commands below.)*

Then I enter the following command...

```
ssh bitnami@<public-ip-address> -i <key-pair-from-aws>.pem
```

... I get the following error:

> Permissions for '(key-pair-from-aws).pem' are too open.
> It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
> This private key will be ignored.
> Load key ".pem": bad permissions
> bitnami@(public-ip-address): Permission denied (publickey).

Now, if I select the file on the PC "Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> disable inheritance", and then remove every user except my user, and then execute the same command ...

```
ssh bitnami@<public-ip-address> -i <key-pair-from-aws>.pem
```

... I get the following error:

```
bitnami@<public-ip-address>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

here I am stuck because I do not have any idea how to proceed further.
Searching on Stackoverflow and google I could not find anything to help me solve this issue.

can anyone please help with concrete, step-by-step instructions?
Thank you!

Update: here is the result of the command
$ ssh -v -i "pem-file-name.pem" bitnami@

```
> OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to <public-ip-address> [<public-ip-address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file kljuc_par_ime.pem type -1
debug1: identity file kljuc_par_ime.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-
5+deb11u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <public-ip-address>:22 as 'bitnami'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit>
compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit>
compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: <deleted for sec purposes> SHA256:<deleted for security purposes>
debug1: Host '<public-ip-address>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\My-User/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: kljuc_par_ime.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.co
m,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp38
4,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-ni
stp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: kljuc_par_ime.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
bitnami@<public-ip-address>: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Comment: Create a new key pair in the EC2 console, download the key pair at that point in ppk format. Create a new EC2 instance and select this keypair. Try to log in using putty. Report back. Please avoid using abbreviations in your question such as "PS" in the first sentence, it's not clear what you mean. Overall it looks like you're using the wrong keypair. Not sure how to log in from Powershell, search for a tutorial, I'm sure it's very common and well documented.